# MessageBox doesn't show all given string

Tags: c#

I have a c# program and am trying to call a messageBox with a specific string(normal string, nothing special), And when reaching a variable to concatenate with the string, it apparently stops the concatenation.
The code:

```
string first = userInfo.info.getFirst(); //Some function
string last = userInfo.info.getLast(); // Some function
string message = first + "_" + last + " !";
MessageBox.Show(message);
// Output will be "(first value)";
```

I did try to debug and the values of "first" and "last" are correct and fine.
I also analyzed to see if any CPU or Memory peak occur(using VS's tools), but seen none.

Any idea as for the problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do either `first` or `last` contain `\0` (the "null" character) anywhere? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: That's exactly it, Thank you! I understand where the problem came from.

Comment: In that case I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Win32 GUI libraries terminate strings if they find a `\0` character (U+0000, Unicode "null") in them. For example, if you had:

```
MessageBox.Show("First part\0Second part");
```

then only `First part` would be displayed.

There are at least two options here:

- Work out where the "bad" character is coming from. It's often a misuse of the `Stream` or `TextReader` API, not paying attention to how many bytes or characters are returned by a `Read` call
- Just remove the "bad" character, e.g. `message = message.Replace("\0", "");`

The first option is preferable - I'd only resort to the second if I *really* couldn't get clean data.